How do I make dynamic properties fatal?
In php < 9 how do I make dynamic properties fatal instead of deprecated?
I have not always the need for a magic __set() or __get() in a small utility function. And really I ask to prevent me from typos, very early.
Also my application probably will hit PHP 9 and I rather have clear early warning (I do not look at logs daily) before this happens.
EDIT: I did have a error handler in place (using MonoLog) so I extended this according to KIKKO Software recommendations. Thank you @KIKKOSoftware!

What do you mean with fatal?

Please [edit] your question to include a description if adding __set() and __get() to your class is an option.

Use set_error_handler(your_handler(), E_DEPRECATED) to intercept deprecations and then scan for the specific error string inside your handler, and generate a fatal if found.

@Progman I have not always the need for a __set/__get for a small utility class. I just want an exception when using a property that does not exist. And yes, I could do that with these magic functions.

You could use set_error_handler() to specifically catch this warning, like so:
set_error_handler(function (int $errorNo, string $message, string $file, int $line): bool
{
    if ($errorNo == E_DEPRECATED) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $errorNo, $file, $line);
    }        
    return TRUE;
});

Demo: https://3v4l.org/tUivC
If you specifically only want to do this for one warning message you could check the content of the $message string. For instance:
if (($errorNo == E_DEPRECATED) && 
    str_contains($message, "Creation of dynamic property")) {
        throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $errorNo, $file, $line);
}


Note that it doesn't work with PHP < 8.2.

@Olivier. Well, yes, but it kind of does, simply because this warning doesn't exist for PHP < 8.2 so there's no way to catch it. You will have to use a separate debugging tool for that. Check what the question is asking: "how do I make dynamic properties fatal instead of deprecated?" It is not deprecated for PHP < 8.2.

@KIKOSoftware yes thanks. There is another reason. I wouldn't mind my current application (in 8.x) fail before it hits PHP 9. I think most of us want that but there is a small group of developers that would benefit from AllowDynamicProperties

Note you can specify E_DEPRECATED as the second argument to set_error_handler(), so that it only intercepts deprecations, and then you don't have to do that check yourself inside your function.
